# Why does $2x^3+4x-4=0$ have only one real root, and how can it be approximated by Newton's method?

Tags: calculus, functions

$ 2x^3+4x-4=0$ equation has exactly one real root. I suppose that I can show it with the intermediate value theorem. How can I get this root with the newton method?

Comment: I ask both of these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y = 2x^3 +4x -4$.

Consider

$y'=6x^2 +4 > 0$

The function is monotonically increasing. Since it is an odd polynomial, we must then have a single real root. Let the root be $x_0$.

Since the $y$-intercept is $-4$, we know $x_0>0$. Also, it is clear by substitution into the original expression that $x_0 <1$.

Make a reasonable estimate $x_0\approx \frac12$ and begin Newton's method.